The issue with NavigationLink animation on iOS
The issue with NavigationLink animation on iOS: When transitioning from details/piyo to settings/piyo, the animation is not enabled on iOS devices. Is this a specification? How can I use the navigation animation when transitioning to a different root URL?
.
├── (tabs)
│   ├── _layout.tsx
│   ├── details
│   │   ├── _layout.tsx
│   │   └── piyo
│   │       └── index.tsx
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── _layout.tsx
│   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   └── piyo
│   │       └── index.tsx
│   └── settings
│       ├── _layout.tsx
│       └── piyo
│           └── index.tsx
├── +html.tsx
├── +not-found.tsx
└── _layout.tsx



// (tab)/index.tsx or (tab)/details/piyo/index.tsx
import { Link } from "expo-router";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        <Link href="/settings/piyo">To other root</Link>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}


Why isn't this animated?
